# CentOS: Can't install PhP GD

Tags: php, linux, centos, php-gd

I have a VPS with CentOS 6 in which I am trying to install PhP GD. I have tried `sudo yum install php-gd` as I read in other StackOverflow questions. When I do this, I get the following:

```
Error: Package: php-gd-5.5.21-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php55)
          Requires: gd-last(x86-64) >= 2.1.0-3
Error: Package: php-gd-5.5.21-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php55)
          Requires: libgd.so.3() (64bit)
```

Any idea on what can I do to install Php-Gd and solve this?

Answer (score 10):

It turns out you need gd-last from epel,

try:

`yum install gd-last --enablerepo=epel`

and then

`yum install php-gd --enablerepo=remi,remi-php55`

Comment: gd-last is a parallel installatiob of latest gd version, available in "remi-safe" (not in EPEL).

Comment: Above approach saved me twice

Answer (score 1):

Install

> ftp://fr2.rpmfind.net/linux/remi/enterprise/6/remi/x86_64/gd-last-2.1.0-3.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm

manually

I had the same issue, and this got everything working.

Answer (score 1):

Permanent link is http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/6/remi/x86_64/repoview/gd-last.html

As explained in remi.repo file and in the FAQ, remi-php55 also need remi for its dependencies (such as this one).

Answer (score 0):

Try this with php5

> yum install php-gd --enablerepo=remi,remi-php55

Answer (score 0):

Puppet users might appreciate this Hiera/YAML code for help dealing with this problem:

```
system::packages:
  'remi-release':
    # ensure: '7.5-2.el7.remi'
    source: 'https://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm'
    provider: 'rpm'

  'php':
    ensure: true
    require:
      - 'Package[remi-release]'

  'php-gd':
    ensure: true
    require:
      - 'Package[remi-release]'
      - 'Exec[enable-remi-safe]'

system::execs:
  'enable-remi-safe':
    command: 'yum-config-manager --enable remi-safe |grep -qEx "^enabled = (1|True)"'
    unless:  'yum-config-manager remi-safe |grep -qEx "^enabled = (1|True)"'
    require: 'Package[remi-release]'
```

The [voxpupuli "system" module](https://github.com/voxpupuli/puppet-system) lets you easily map hiera keys and values into standard resource primitives. If you don't use Hiera or System, this above 'code' is easily done using the standard puppet resource declarations.