# gd library installation error for php81 in amazon linus 2

Tags: php, amazon-ec2

In my server there are two php version run simultaneously (php = 5.6 and php = 8.1)
When I run

**sudo yum install php81-php-gd** the following error occured

I tried:

`sudo yum install gd-last --enablerepo=epel` and 
 `yum install php-gd --enablerepo=remi,remi-php81`

from [centos-cant-install-php-gd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28120410/centos-cant-install-php-gd) 
It doesn't work to me.

**error log:**

> Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
>
>  286 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
>
>  Resolving Dependencies 
> --> Running transaction check 
> ---> Package php81-php-gd.x86_64 0:8.1.10-1.el7.remi will be installed 
> --> Processing Dependency: libgd.so.103()(64bit) for package: php81-php-gd-8.1.10-1.el7.remi.x86_64 
> --> Running transaction check 
> ---> Package gd-last.x86_64 0:2.2.5-10.el7.remi will be obsoleted
> --> Processing Dependency: gd-last(x86-64) >= 2.1.1 for package: php-gd-5.6.40-18.el7.remi.x86_64 
> --> Processing Dependency: libgd.so.3()(64bit) for package: php-gd-5.6.40-18.el7.remi.x86_64 
> ---> Package gd3php.x86_64 0:2.3.3-7.el7.remi will be obsoleting 
> --> Processing Dependency: libraqm.so.0()(64bit) for package: gd3php-2.3.3-7.el7.remi.x86_64 
> --> Running transaction check 
> ---> Package gd-last.x86_64 0:2.2.5-10.el7.remi will be obsoleted 
> --> Processing Dependency: gd-last(x86-64) >= 2.1.1 for package: php-gd-5.6.40- 
>  18.el7.remi.x86_64 
> --> Processing Dependency: libgd.so.3()(64bit) for package: php-gd-5.6.40-18.el7.remi.x86_64 
> ---> Package libraqm.x86_64 0:0.7.0-4.el7 will be installed 
> --> Processing Dependency: libfribidi.so.0()(64bit) for package: libraqm-0.7.0-4.el7.x86_64 
> --> Running transaction check 
> ---> Package fribidi.x86_64 0:1.0.2-1.amzn2.1 will be installed 
> ---> Package gd-last.x86_64 0:2.2.5-10.el7.remi will be obsoleted 
> --> Processing Dependency: gd-last(x86-64) >= 2.1.1 for package: php-gd-5.6.40- 
>  18.el7.remi.x86_64 
> --> Processing Dependency: libgd.so.3()(64bit) for package: php-gd-5.6.40-18.el7.remi.x86_64 
> --> Finished Dependency Resolution 
>  Error: Package: php-gd-5.6.40-18.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php56) 
> Requires: libgd.so.3()(64bit) 
> Removing: gd-last-2.2.5-10.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-safe) 
> libgd.so.3()(64bit) 
> Obsoleted By: gd3php-2.3.3-7.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-safe) 
> ~libgd.so.103()(64bit) 
>  Error: Package: php-gd-5.6.40-18.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php56) 
> Requires: gd-last(x86-64) >= 2.1.1 
> Removing: gd-last-2.2.5-10.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-safe) 
> gd-last(x86-64) = 2.2.5-10.el7.remi 
> Obsoleted By: gd3php-2.3.3-7.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-safe) 
> Not found 
>    You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem 
>   You could try running: rpm -Va
> --nofiles --nodigest

Answer (score 0):

> Error: Package: php-gd-5.6.40-18.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php56)

This is not the latest version (5.6.40-33 with lot of security fixes)
Please upgrade everything

For a proper configuration, follow the [Wizard instructions](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/)

In your case, you need **remi-php56** to be enabled.

Also better to ask such question to dedicated [forum](https://forum.remirepo.net/), [github issue tracker](https://github.com/remicollet/remirepo/issues).